# div not showing up

Tags: jquery

I have some problem with the following code:

```
<input type="radio" name="subscription" id="subscription" value="yes" checked="checked"  />Yes
<input type="radio" name="subscription" id="subscription" value="no" />No

<div id="sub_yes" style="display:none;background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #ccc">
    [ some code here ]
</div>
```

Now I have jQuery as

```
if(jQuery('input[name|="subscription"]').val()=='yes') {
  jQuery('#sub_yes').fadeIn(0, function(){ 
                                 jQuery(this).slideDown('slow','swing');
                                }); 
}
```

When document get ready, jQuery checks value of "subscription" and if it's yes, then it should show div named "sub_yes", But this code is not working.

Please help

Comment: just FYI: there is an error in your code regarding element IDs - you cannot have 2 elements with the SAME id on page (id="subscription"), since each ID is unique and browsers would not know what to search for (should the need to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just checking the value of subscription radio button. There should be a click event checker also, so that whenever you click the radio button it should check the value and react accordingly.

```
jQuery('input[name|="subscription"]').click(function(){
if(jQuery('input[name|="subscription"]').val()=='yes') {
  jQuery('#sub_yes').fadeIn(0, function(){ 
                                 jQuery(this).slideDown('slow','swing');
                                }); 
}
});
```

Hope this solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

found the solution:

I added **:checked**

```
jQuery('input[name|="subscription"]:checked').val()=='yes'
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type="radio" name="subscription" id="subscription" value="yes" checked="checked"  />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="subscription2" id="subscription2" value="no" />No

    <div id="sub_yes" style="display:none;background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #ccc">
        [ some code here ]
    </div>


    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
    var val=$(this).val();
    if(val=="yes"){
    $('#sub_yes').fadeIn(0, function(){ 
                                     $(this).slideDown('slow','swing');
                                    }); 
    return;
    }

    });



});
```

hope it helps

**Edit:**
instead of display:none u can use

```
$("#sub_yes").hide();
```

in document ready and to show the div u can use `.show()`